# Java HTTP call on WSL 1 fails with 'cannot assign the requested address'

Tags: java, rest, http, https, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running on WSL1 on Windows 10. Using Azul OpenJDK 8 for Linux.

Below is a simple code for making an outbound HTTP connection :

```java
private void invokeREST() throws MalformedURLException {

        final String REST_URI = "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/posts";

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(REST_URI);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error when executing :

```sh
./gradlew run

> Task :run
Mar 17, 2022 11:07:21 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://gorest.co.in:443: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)
Mar 17, 2022 11:07:21 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect to {s}->https://gorest.co.in:443
Mar 17, 2022 11:07:21 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://gorest.co.in:443: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)
Mar 17, 2022 11:07:21 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect to {s}->https://gorest.co.in:443
Mar 17, 2022 11:07:21 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to {s}->https://gorest.co.in:443: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)
Mar 17, 2022 11:07:21 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect to {s}->https://gorest.co.in:443
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:613)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:543)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:415)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.experiment.restTest.simpleHTTPRequest(restTest.java:51)
        at com.experiment.restTest.invokeREST(restTest.java:42)
        at com.experiment.restTest.main(restTest.java:121)
```

The call works successfully when executed using Java 8 for Windows

```
.\gradlew run

> Task :compileJava
Note: C:\Users\tester\IdeaProjects\testProject\src\main\java\com\experiment\restTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :run
[{"id":1337,"user_id":2822,"title":"Cimentarius quasi tero alii vel cibus sollicito volup solio laudantium adipiscor.","body":"Bos certe cruentus. Unde candidus volva. Stabilis accipio vinculum. Maiores vicinus amplus. Contabesco autem tubineus. Animadverto celo civitas. Sustineo omnis saepe. Alioqui tamen ocer. Succurro id conscendo. Blanditiis ."}]
```

I disabled the wifi network interface (via powershell) in case there was a conflict, but it did not make a difference.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netsh interface show interface

Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Npcap Loopback Adapter
Disabled       Disconnected   Dedicated        Wi-Fi
Disabled       Disconnected   Dedicated        Citrix Virtual Adapter
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        vEthernet (Internal switch)
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Ethernet
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        vEthernet (Default Switch)
```

curl command works successfully as well.

Has anyone experience a similar issue in WSL 1 with Java ?

Comment: What happens if you execute `curl https://gorest.co.in` inside the WSL terminal?

Comment: curl command is successful. I'm not sure if this is network issue specific to java.

Comment: What version of org.apache.http do you use?

Comment: For Apache HTTP, using version 4.15.3.  I was using Jersey Client initially when implementing the connection, but encountered the same issue.  Using Apache HTTP to just test a simple connection.